# pass a method in a class that takes parameters to pug file node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to pass a method in a class that takes parameters to pug file node js :

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const trends = await service.getTrendingVideos();

//const t1 = service.getVideoDetails(video);


  res.render('youtube/index', {
    title: config.title,
    videos: trends,
    cal: service


  });
});
```

Comment: I want const t1 = service.getVideoDetails(video); to be passed and used in pug. A code to do this will be very helpful please

Comment: What have you tried? What errors does it show? You can't expect us to write code for you.

Comment: I need to know the process. i dont know how it works for now

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Did you try something?

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. node js

Comment: I still can't clearly understand what you want.

Comment: I am querying with js a youtube api. I have gotten a list of trending videos. Am trying to get video statics with the id. Its giving me promise errors

Comment: Sorry was really tired from trying stuff

Comment: Oh, alright! Can you post the errors it's giving you? I can help you solve it! :)

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. node js

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `service.getVideoDetails(video)` is async, call it with `await` as when calling the `service.getTrendingVideos()`. Then you can pass `t1` into the pug template.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const trends = await service.getTrendingVideos();
  const details = await service.getVideoDetails(video);
  res.render('youtube/index', { /* use the trends and details objects here */ });
});
```

Comment: video is not defined

Comment: Yep, the commented line in your code references the `video` variable, so you should make sure it's available.

Comment: video is an array I need to iterate in a index.pug file

Comment: am asking how I can transfer getVideoDetails() to the pug and call on iteration

Comment: Ok, well next time please explain that clearly in the question. I’d suggest that you iterate through the videos in the JavaScript code and _then_ send the results to the template.

Comment: Thanks good thinking. But is there a way to separate the html from the logic.

Comment: (node:2032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Solved. I did my iteration on the route using await when referring to getvideodetails function to enable all promises to be fulfilled